# Getting Tap/Touch Position when selecting a TableView cell

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, touch

hope to get some help here because this is something that really makes me mad...

I have a view with a tableView, and when I tap a cell I want to present a popOver window pointing the arrow to the cell I tapped.

the things that I think I need is:
1- the position of the cell in the screen (not in the view, because on large tables the Y value of the cell's rect could be grater than screen hight)

or

2- a CGPoint or something similar that represents the point in the screen I tapped.

I can't figured this out, and makes me really mad!!!

Any help will very very very very usefull.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `UIView` method `convertPoint:toView:` (using nil as the toView argument).

If I trigger a UIPopoverController from a cell tap, I usually just have it come from the cell, thus:

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:cell.frame inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Paull!!! the UIView method you recommend is very useful.. but I really didn't use it :D.

You give me an idea when passing the cell as the view to present the popover, I was using "self.view", and I've changed it to self.tableView and it works perfect! jeje

Thank you so much!!!
You're the SH@# ;)